# Converting Dates in Mule 4 (Salesforce to Oracle)

Tags: datetime, mule, dataweave

I've been trying to convert a date field from a Salesforce Query and inserting the record into an Oracle table.
I had alot of trouble with the format,
As the input is being treated as a string so as Date{format: "yyyy-MM-dd ' 'HH:mm:ss"} isn't working.

Input:
2019-02-12T00:52:21.000Z

Required Output:
2019-02-12 00:52:21

I've tried doing this in a Transform Message and in the Input Parameters in the Database Insert.

Eventually I found an answer and I wanted to share it here,
As it's a string it can be solved with string manipulation.
Here's my answer:
CREATED_AT:(payload.CreatedDate splitBy"T")[0] ++ " " ++ (((payload.CreatedDate splitBy"T")[1]) splitBy".")[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi another way to solve this is by converting your string to a DateTime and then to a String

```
("2019-02-12T00:52:21.000Z" as DateTime) as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
```

This will result what you expected to

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found an answer and I wanted to share it here, As it's a string it can be solved with string manipulation. Here's my answer: CREATED_AT:(payload.CreatedDate splitBy"T")[0] ++ " " ++ (((payload.CreatedDate splitBy"T")[1]) splitBy".")[0]